# Question using Young inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

In fact i am looking for $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ such that the following inequality is true:$a^\frac{1}{80}\le \alpha_1\frac{a^{\frac{1}{4}}}{b^{\frac{3}{4}}c^6}+\alpha_2b^{\frac{1}{16}}+\alpha_3 c^{\alpha_4}$ for all $a,b,c $ strictly positive numbers.
Here is my answer
$a^\frac{1}{80}b^{\frac{3}{4}}c^6\le \frac{1}{20}a^{\frac{1}{4}}+\frac{19}{20}(b^{\frac{15}{19}}c^{\frac{120}{19}})$
$\le \frac{1}{20}a^{\frac{1}{4}}+\frac{19}{20}(\frac{240}{19}b^{\frac{1}{16}}-\frac{239}{19}c^{\frac{-120}{239}})$

for all $a,b,c$ strictely positive.
Please help me to correct it.

Thanks.

Comment: If $a,b,c$ are three fixed numbers, can you not simply solve for $\alpha$? Are you instead looking for an $\alpha$ that will work for a more general set of $a,b,c$?

Comment: yes i am looking for $\alpha$ that work for general set of $a,b,c$ .Can you please help me?

Comment: No hypothesis on $a, b,c$?

Comment: Still looks false: put $a=1,b^{1/16}=1.6,c=0.4$. Right hand side is about $0.8$.

Comment: I edited the question .Please help (:

Comment: Take $a=c=1,b=5$. Then $a^{1/30}b^{3/4}c^6=3.34$, the next expression is 3.07 and the last is 1.37. But the 1st is supposed to be less than the 2nd, which is supposed to be less than the 3rd.

Comment: here is my final answer i hope it is correct;http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1793357/young-inequality-question

Answer (score 0):

If we plug in $a=b=c=1$ into
$$
a^{\frac1{80}}\le\frac1{20}\frac{a^{\frac14}}{b^{\frac34}c^6}+\frac6{20}b^{\frac1{16}}+\frac3{20}c^\alpha
$$
we get that $1\le\frac12$. This doesn't seem promising.

Comment: Hi robjohn ,i changed the inequality .can you see it again please?thanks in advance